# SQL array only output last answer

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to make a pdf-library where users can fill in which pdf-files they want to download and then the PHP file will get the filename from a database and make a path to the file and then it should download all selected files. But  only get the last file downloaded.

This is my code for the download/output from the database:
Grateful for answer

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pdf WHERE id='$check'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
            
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $path = $row["path"];
        $filename = $row["name"];
        $file = $path."/".$filename;
                        
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        readfile($file);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: you override your header in the while-loop

Comment: Can you explain how you get $check variable? If possible can you please update the question how you get $check variable

Answer (score 1):

You can't send multiple files in a single response and you can't give multiple responses to a single request.

You might build an array of files to be downloaded and instruct the client (probably javascript in the browser) to request the files. Or you could zip them in a single ball and respond with that.